# Is the identity map a retraction?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm sort of wrestling with the definition of retraction in my head. The definition I was given was the following:

> A retraction of a space $X$ onto a subspace $Z \subseteq X$ is a continuous map $r$ s.t. $r(z) = z \in Z, \forall z \in Z$.

Now to me this just seems like the definition of an identity map, so essentially the map $r$ is an identity on $Z$ but doesn't really care about what happen to points outside of $Z$.
So my question is the identity map a retraction? If it is then wouldn't any subspace of a topological space be a retract of the identity map? Can someone clarify or confirm whether my reasoning is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The retraction must be onto **$\color{red}Z$**, it can't leave the points outside of $Z$ unchanged, they must go into $Z$.

Comment: "can't leave the points outside of Z unchanged" from what part of the definition this follows from?

Comment: @mathripper: It’s implicit in its description as aa retraction **onto** $Z$. The definition really ought to have said that it’s continuous map $r:X\to Z$ such that etc.

Comment: That's why I color in red $Z$, I wouldn't  say it's implicit, it's explicitly stated in the definition.

Answer (score 2):

You've correctly deduced that the identity map $i:X \rightarrow X $ is a retraction. Note that if $Z$ is a proper subset of $X$ then the function $f: X \rightarrow Z$ cannot be the identity as it would fail to be a function.